# Valgrind memory leak in vector

Tags: c, vector, valgrind

Right now I have a very simple program which adds the input string from stdin to a vect structure called command_list.

```
#define MAX_CHARS = 256;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char input[MAX_CHARS];
  vect_t* command_list = vect_new();

  // After starting, the shell should print a welcome message:
  printf("Hi!\n");

  while (1) {
    printf("input: ");
    if (fgets(input, MAX_CHARS, stdin) == NULL) {
      printf("bye.\n");
      break;
    }

    // Add input to the command list 
    vect_add(command_list, input);

    // while command list is not empty, 
    while (vect_size(command_list) != 0) {
      // get the first element
      char* front = vect_get_copy(command_list, 0);
      // ...
      free(front);
      // remove the first element
      vect_remove_first(command_list);
    }
  }
  // free command_list
  vect_delete(command_list);

  return 0;
}
```

However, when I run `echo "cd" | valgrind --leak-check=full ./shell`, it gives me the following memory leak information,

```
==196780== 
==196780== HEAP SUMMARY:
==196780==     in use at exit: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==196780==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 11 frees, 5,222 bytes allocated
==196780== 
==196780== 10 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==196780==    at 0x48487A9: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==196780==    by 0x10B1CA: vect_add (vect.c:139)
==196780==    by 0x10A052: main (shell.c:79)
==196780== 
==196780== LEAK SUMMARY:
==196780==    definitely lost: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==196780==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==196780==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==196780==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==196780==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==196780== 
==196780== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==196780== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

It says that the leak is from vect_add. Below is my vect structure, vect_add, and vect_delete I used in the program,

```
typedef struct vect vect_t;

/** Main data structure for the vector. */
struct vect {
  char **data;             /* Array containing the actual data. */
  unsigned int size;       /* Number of items currently in the vector. */
  unsigned int capacity;   /* Maximum number of items the vector can hold before growing. */
};

/** Delete the vector, freeing all memory it occupies. */
void vect_delete(vect_t *v) {
  if (v == NULL) {
    return;
  }

  /* [TODO] Complete the function */
  // Delete data one by one because they are allocated memory for in other functions

  int size = v->size;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    vect_remove_last(v);
  }
  // Free v->data because memory is allocated for it in vect_new
  free(v->data);
  // Delete the vector
  free(v);
}

/** Add an element to the back of the vector. */
void vect_add(vect_t *v, const char *elt) {
  assert(v != NULL);

  /* [TODO] Complete the function */
 // If the array is full
  if (v->size >= v->capacity) {
    char **tmp = v->data;
    // Reallocate memory for the array
    v->capacity *= VECT_GROWTH_FACTOR;
    v->data = (char**) realloc(tmp, (v->capacity) * sizeof(*v->data));
    if (v->data == NULL) {
      return;
    }
    // Initialize the elements in the expanded part of the array to NULL
    for (int i = v->size; i < v->capacity; i++) {
      v->data[i] = NULL;
    }
  }
  // Reallocate memory for the element at v->size to be able to store elt
  v->data[v->size] = (char*) realloc(v->data[v->size], strlen(elt)+1);
  if (v->data[v->size] == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  strcpy(v->data[v->size], elt);
  v->size++;
}
```

I am really struggling to find out where the memory leak comes from. Where did I not free anything properly? Please help.

Edit:

Added vect_remove_first

```
/** Remove the first element from the vector. */
void vect_remove_first(vect_t *v) {
  assert(v != NULL);

  /* [TODO] Complete the function */
  // Shift the elements to the left by one
  int i = 1;
  for (; i < v->size; i++) {
    if (v->data[i] == NULL) {
      break;
    } else {
      v->data[i-1] = realloc(v->data[i-1], strlen(v->data[i])+1);
      strcpy(v->data[i-1], v->data[i]);
    }
  }
  v->data[i] = NULL;
  v->size -= 1;
}
```

Comment: you're not showing `vect_remove_last`

Comment: Print something after each `malloc` and `free`, and see if you have a free for each malloc.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre just added! I assume something is wrong there. But I am still thinking

Comment: @Barmar how can I do that?

Comment: Something like: `free(v->data); printf("Freeing v->data\n");`

Comment: memcheck is telling you that the leak is on line 139 of vect.c. Use a debugger and count how many times you call `malloc`and `free`

Comment: Where is `vect_new` ?

Comment: `vect_get_copy` and `vect_size` is also missing

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** After posting Part 1, I found another and more likely memory leak. Part 1 is still relevant butperhaps read Part 2 first.

**PART 1:**

The posted code isn't complete so it's not possible to fully check the code but here is one potential problem.

The use of `realloc` may lead to memory leaks if `realloc` fails.

When/if `realloc` can't allocate the requested memory, it returns NULL and leaves the original memory unchanged which includes "still allocated". So the safe way of using `realloc` is:

```
void * tmp = realloc(ptr, size);
if (tmp != NULL)
{
    ptr = tmp;
}
else
{
    // Error handler....
}
```

and somewhere later in the code do `free(ptr);`

The posted code has a number of `realloc` that saves the return value directly into the original pointer, e.g.

```
v->data[i-1] = realloc(v->data[i-1], strlen(v->data[i])+1);
```

which may lead to memory leaks unless you know that `v->data[i-1]` is NULL when calling `realloc`. However, if that is known, you should use `malloc` instead to make the code more clear.

In this code block:

```
char **tmp = v->data;
// Reallocate memory for the array
v->capacity *= VECT_GROWTH_FACTOR;
v->data = (char**) realloc(tmp, (v->capacity) * sizeof(*v->data));
if (v->data == NULL) {
  return;
}
```

it seems that you try to use a `tmp` pointer for the `realloc`. But it's the wrong way. The return value is stored into `v->data` and in case of NULL the function returns without freeing `tmp`. Again a potential memory leak. Did you intend to do `if (v->data == NULL) { free(tmp); return; }`

Besides that it seems wrong to use a return in that case. Code executed later may dereference a NULL pointer and crash. Maybe you wanted `exit(FAILURE)` instead of `return`

**PART 2:**

A quick look at `vect_remove_first` made me suspicious...

How can it be that a function removing an element has no call of `free` ?

That seems like a bug causing leaks. And it is...

In case the vector is full, i.e. all pointers in `data` are non-NULL, you need to call `free` on the last element.

Further, with a "full" vector you do access out of bounds when you do `v->data[i] = NULL;` as `i` will equal `v->size`

That said... Why do you do all that `realloc` and `strcpy`? It's way to complex and slow. And you don't need it!

You have an array of pointers so you can just move the pointer values.

In principle like:

```
free(v->data[0]);
v->data[0] = v->data[1];
v->data[1] = v->data[2];
...
v->data[v->size - 2] = v->data[v->size - 1];
v->data[v->size - 1] = NULL;
```

The real implementation would be a loop or perhaps a `memmove`. With `memmove` the code will be real simple but performance will most likely be worse when the fill level is low.